# Angularjs: 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token , ' when loading object

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, xslt, symphony-cms

I'm trying to use [Symphony CMS](http://www.getsymphony.com/) to output its XSL as JSON, for use in the [angular phonecat app](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00) example from the tutorial. My list view json is output as an array with [{ }] brackets around it. My detail view json is output with only { } around it:

```
{
 "position": 1,
 "order": 3,
 "total": "1",
 "id": "sunt",
 "sym_id": "21",
 "cat": "back-end",
 "imageUrl": "http://localhost:8080/workspace/images/phones/Nondell-streak-7.0.jpg",
 "name": "Sunt",
 "done": "No",
 "priority": "medium",
 "date-created" : "18 November 2015",
 "date-modified" : "19/11/15 10:41am",
 "date-due" : "18/11/15 2:13pm",
 "snippet": "Quam nihil molestiae"
}
```

When loading my page the list view loads. When I click on an item the detail view tries to load but I get: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,**. Why? The syntax seems normal to me?

A big problem I am struggling with is that my json is created dynamically with the CMS but no actual files are on the server as far as I know.

Before I was getting the error: *Error in resource configuration for action get. Expected response to contain an object but got an array* so I made some changes so the list is output as an array, and the single views are output as an object.

My json is generated on `localhost:8080/json/{parameter}`. The param is 'todos' when not set. So my list view is situated at `localhost:8080/json/todos`. The param takes the selected object's name, so my detail view would be at `localhost:8080/json/foo` when I press the link generated by angular.

I hope my question is complete and makes sense :D

Comment: do you set content-type as application/json on the response?

Comment: When I run curl --head http://localhost:8080/json/foo | grep Content-Type i get text/html
When I run curl --head http://localhost:8080/json/foo/ | grep Content-Type i get application/json
This rewrite rule is in the htacces
RewriteRule ^(.*\/?)\.json$ index.php?symphony-page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}    [L]

Comment: Someone on a chat has commented: "it may be an authentication token.
It depend on how you do authentication on your site. Do you need to be logged in to get a respond?"

Comment: I don't know. but take a look at this might be helpful . http://symphonyextensions.com/extensions/rest_api/ ,http://www.getsymphony.com/discuss/thread/87298/

Comment: Thanks for the extension, I saw the thread :). Still curious what the cause might be of this problem.